# Regarding netconf tags

Tags: cisco, ietf-netconf

From one of the docs, i have the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rpc message-id="${TIMESTAMP}" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <get-config>
    <source>
    <running></running>
    </source>
    <filter>
    <interface-configurations xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ifmgr-cfg"/>

    </filter>
    </get-config>
</rpc>
```

This actually retrieves the interface configuration from the running config
and works OK

Q1:How do i edit the same to retrieve interface statistics? What tags need to be used? How do i come to know?

Q2:I changed the line containing the namespace to some random line like 'http://a.b.c.d/check' and it failed. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i edit the same to retrieve interface statistics? What tags need to be used? How do i come to know?

Your example uses `<get-config>` standard operation, which only retrieves configuration, not operational state. If you wish to retrieve the latter, you need to use `<get/>`, which retrieves both configuration and state data.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rpc xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="${TIMESTAMP}">
  <get>
    <filter>
      <interface-configurations xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ifmgr-cfg"/>
    </filter>
  </get>
</rpc>
```

There is no `<source>` parameter for this one, since it always retrieves running config plus operational state. The easiest way to get familiar with NETCONF, would be to read its [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6241).

> I changed the line containing the namespace to some random line like 'http://a.b.c.d/check' and it failed. Why?

If by "failed" you meant that you received an `<rpc-error>`, that would be non-standard behavior. You should have gotten an empty `<data/>` response, since there are no nodes that match your filter. The filter requires an exact match.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="163">
  <data/>
</rpc-reply>
```

NETCONF datastores rely heavily on namespaces since that solves the most common naming problems. For example, if you have two modules and they contain top-level elements that are named "my-config", you won't have a problem, because they are uniquely identified by module namespaces: `{uri:a}my-config` and `{uri:b}my-config`.

In your example, you asked for `{http://a.b.c.d/check}interface-configurations`, which simply does not exist. It is irrelevant that the `interface-configuration` part matches (local name), because you requested a specific `interface-configuration` from a specific namespace.

Namespaces are (kind of) like house addresses. There may be numerous John Smiths in existence, but you can address a specific one by stating his full address. If you ask your local post to send a package to just the name "John Smith", without an address, the post would have no idea which one you meant.

Note: if you meant that you changed the `urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0` line, then the problem is the same. You attempted to execute some operation unknown to the server. This case would fail with an error response, however.

Comment: thanks for detailed response...also need to confirm that whatever netconf tags(as seen above in form of xml) we write, there is a corresponding underlying yang model for the same? This yang model is used to validate the netconf xml file.Is that correct undertstanding? If so, how can i retrieve the corresonding yang model for the above xml?

Comment: YANG is used to model content that is sent between a server and a client. You can picture it as a contract between peers that ensures no "surprises" occur during communication - such as unknown elements, text values, etc. It only deals with the [fourth layer](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6241#section-1.2) of the protocol, the content layer. You will need to consult with the maker of the device in question in order to obtain appropriate YANG model. Some devices support the optional `<get-schema>`  operation (ietf-netconf-monitoring module), allowing you to retrieve YANG.

Comment: *fourth and third layer, not just the former.

Comment: tried the <get> operation, however, i still receive only configuration data...there is nothing like state data(which i assume would be something of the sort interface statistics,inout/output queue etc)

Comment: This could just mean that the particular branch you are selecting has no state nodes defined. Try removing the filter altogether - this will get you everything on the device.

Comment: Tried and received   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rpc-reply message-id="1475748932" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
 <rpc-error>
  <error-type>application</error-type>
  <error-tag>operation-not-supported</error-tag>
  <error-severity>error</error-severity>
  <error-message xml:lang="en">&lt;get&gt; operation without filter is not supported by this implementation.</error-message>
 </rpc-error>
</rpc-reply>   That's what i  asking...how would you know when to pass parameters and when not to...when to what namespace exactly..for example how a beginner would know exact namespac

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but your device is one of the older Cisco devices which are far from NETCONF compliant. I have encountered those before and there is not much you can do with them - as far as NETCONF goes. Check if you can upgrade the firmware.